# PPTP VPN Linux To PPTP Windows Server

Tags: linux, docker, vpn, client, pptp

На данный момент имеется **PPTP Client в Docker контейнере** на основе образа **nginx:alpine**, который пытается подключиться предположительно к удалённому
PPTP Windows Server'у

```
$ pon vps
using channel 1
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1  asyncmap 0x0 magic 0x1865a2ab pcomp accomp]
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

Из-за этой строки нагуглил, что нужно поставить недостающие модули
`LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests`

Я пытаюсь поставить недостающие модули в свой контейнер:

```
nf_conntrack_pptp 
nf_conntrack_proto_gre
```

Использую для этого следующую команду:

```
$ modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
```

После чего была попытка создать директорию с этим путём

```
$ mkdir /lib/modules
$ modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
modprobe: can't change directory to '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2': No such file or directory
```

После чего попытался сделать так:

```
$ mkdir /lib/modules/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
modprobe: can't open 'modules.dep': No such file or directory
```

И последним моим потугом была эта команда:

```
$ depmod -a
depmod: can't open 'modules.builtin': No such file or directory
```

Кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой? Как это решить и установить недостающие модули в docker контейнер

Comment: Контейнеры - это вроде как не про ядро и виртуальные машины, а про изоляцию процессов на одной и той же системе. Мне кажется, вы как минимум не в том месте ядро ковыряете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было довольно простым, контейнер с PPTP клиентом я разместил на компьютере где установлен Linux Debian и установлен Docker
После чего я на этой машине прописал команду

```
$ modprobe nf_conntrack_pptp
```

следующей командой, которую пришлось ввести:

```
$ sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```

Это и было решением моей проблемы

Теперь PPTP Client подключается к удаленному серверу